# How to add/set new environmental varaible in Azure web app web.config file

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have one application deployed on Microsoft Azure Web App. In that I have created web.config file.

I have 2 custom domain linked to my web app

1. api-stage.example.com
2. api-prev.example.com

I want to set 1 environment variable named PLATFORM when my API is accessed.
Eg. When I access api using api-stage.example.com I want to set value of PLATFORM to stage and when I access api using api-prev.example.com, I want to set value of PLATFORM to prev.

I access this env variable in code like below
`$platform = getenv('PLATFORM');`

Content of my web.config file looks like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="true">
        </httpProtocol>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
        </staticContent>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ABC" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
            <remove name="PHP56_via_FastCGI" />
            <add name="PHP56_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, OPTION, DELETE, PUT, TRACE" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Can anybody help me how to do this? Which block I need to add in web.config file. I cannot do this using Azure Portal via Application Setting, because it allows me to set only one value for PLATFORM varaible. But I want to set and access it using hostname which i am using to call an API.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set variables in the portal, you could refer to this doc: [Configure app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-app-settings).

> For ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core developers, setting app settings in App Service are like setting them in  in Web.config or appsettings.json

**Note**:values in App Service override the ones in Web.config or appsettings.json.  For other languages, the doc also provide the link.

And the below is my test. Trying to use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["testkey"]` to get the value.

[image]

[image]

Hope this could help you. And from your description, you deploy two environment webs into one app service,one is stage and one is prev. So why not try the [staging slots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots) if you are using Standard, Premium, or Isolated App Service plan tier.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I was trying to use same code for 2 separate product with different functionalities based on PLATFORM variable value. AppSetting will be for entire web app. It cannot be use on the basis of hostname. So I used other approach suggested by you. I created staging slot.

Comment: @Crue, if this could help you, please accept it as the answer.